# Geographic permissions in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

Is it possible to set different geographic permission to different users/roles in Geoserver?

I guess one solution would be to create different layers where each layer only shows information in that specific region. And then you set the permission on the layer. 
But if you have many different "geographic permissions" that would take a lot of time to set up.

So is there a way, in GeoServer, to set a geographic boundary for a user to only view information within that boundary?

Comment: Another way of doing it would be to pass through permissions to a PostGIS database, then handle the location component at the database level, such as by creating child tables for specific users, though that could be as unwieldy as having different layers for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question. But I'm afraid that this is not possible. I can't see another option than to set up different layers like you already propose.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Look like I have a couple of layers to add :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to display, you could use a vector layer and only retrieve the data via a ajax call from the database relevant to that particular users logon. It would still mean mapping the user to the different data in the database that they were allowed to see, does not matter what approach you adopt, this will be necessary anyway.